# Private domain for clients, not for public

Tags: dns, private, bots

I have 2 domains:

1) mydomain.com (for my public site, my normal domain for everyone that shows products, services etc...)

2) myclientportal.com (this one is for clients only)

My question is:

What can I do to make sure the `myclientportal.com` does not show up on any search engine?

Since it's a "private" or "member" domain I don't want any traffic on this domain publicly, therefore, I don't want this domain to show up on search engine. I only want registered users that use our services.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously, you can't prevent your clients from mistakenly creating public links to your private site.

Two thing you want to do.

1- Create a robots.txt file that tells robots to go away.  Put this file at the content root of your site, and in it put:

```
User-agent: * Disallow: /
```

Note that this tells robots to go away, but does not *force* them to respect your wishes.
If you want to ensure that nobody other then your clients ever even sees the root page for this private site then I would suggest

2- Adding authentication at the web server level.  If you are using Apache, start here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll want to do is set your robots.txt file. Just google "robots.txt" and you'll find enough to start.

Then you'll want to think about limiting access to your clients' IP addresses only.